# Replace all matched queries (search params) with bold tag in JS/TS with case-insensitive mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I want to replace all matched queries with bold tag in TypeScript. (Using react here).

I have a string like `"morocco & morocco"`. In this string lets say our query is `"mo"`. Then output should be:

```
"<b>mo</b>rocco & <b>mo</b>rocco".
```

And I want to do this case-insensitive way.

```
"<b>mO</b>roCCo& <b>MO</b>ROCCO".
```

What I tried so far but it hangs to thread:

```
const query: string = 'mo';
let text: string = 'morocco & morocco';
const re: RegExp = new RegExp(query, "g");
let m: any = null;
do {
  m = re.exec(text);
  if (m) {
    const q: string = m[0];
    text = text.replace(q, `<b>${q}</b>`);
  }
} while (m)
```

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8fep7s

Comment: I don't know typescript, but what's wrong with `text = text.replace(/mo/ig, '<b>$&</b>')` (apart from the whole HTML injection issue)?

Comment: Yes, that worked. One line.